# Making an object equal to another object

Tags: object, equals

I'm writing 2 Vectors:

```
PVector a = new PVector (5,6);
PVector b = a;
b.add(new PVector (2,2));
print(a);
```

Why does a = (7,8)?

I didn't change a, I changed b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PVector b = a;

It didn't actually created new object of PVector, but made a reference to the vector a.

Therefore you have 2 references to the one place in the memory where is PVector(5,6) and when you add sth using one reference it will surely impact on the other one.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thankyou! so what to do if you dont want that reference, ony for the value of b to be the same as the value of b, but then change b and dont alter a

Comment: You can use PVector b = new PVector(a.x, a.y). Then you will have 2 different objects and easily affect only one of them :) If answer was useful, mark it :)